# Connect to Marvel database using Angular 1.6

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to connect to the Marvel database to my search. For some reason it does not work. Something is slipping away from me and I do not know what. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is the fragment of the code:

```
var app = angular.module("marvelcomic", ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $locatie, $http) {


$scope.comicInfo = false;
$scope.getComic = function() {

  $http({

    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics',
    params: {
      apiKey: '5234a931fdd1da574fb6133e31a6d02c',
      ts: Date.now()
    }
  }).then(function(response){
    $scope.charInfoArr = response.data.data.results;
    return response.data.data.results.map(function(item) {

      return item.name;
    });
  }).error(function(error) {

    console.error(error);
  });
}
  }
//$scope.functieTest = function() {
  //alert("apasat");
  //};
);
```

Comment: Try looking in Chrome's Developer Tools Network panel.

Comment: Can you detail please? I am new to this. Thank you!

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools